# Virtual Box does not start Genymotion machine

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, genymotion

Virtual box version 5.0.28 , genymotion on running device gives error: Virtual Box cannot start virtual device.On running virtual device from virtual box it shows error :The virtual machine 'Google Nexus 5 - 4.4.4 - API 19 - 1080x1920' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).[image: error:]

Please help me out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem tonight. I uninstalled VirtualBox, and I still had OpenVPN from my on-call days, which I also uninstalled. I then uninstalled Genymotion.

Re-installed Genymotion, and then re-installed VirtualBox. Removed the old Android image I had, and after downloading a new image in Genymotion, things worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. updating VirtualBox and Genymotion solved the problem.

first update VirtualBox => menu => file => check for updates
then after updating VirtualBox open Genymotion, it shows a message that you should upate Genymotion. click update and that's it.